String Escape Inconsistencies Snowflake vs dbt
I'm cleaning an array-like string so that it's a proper array type with proper quoting.
Example Input:
['Home & Kitchen / Kitchen & Dining / Dining & Entertaining / Glassware & Drinkware'  'Home & Kitchen / Kitchen & Dining / Dining & Entertaining / Novelty / Drinkware / Coffee Mugs']

Current Code:
array_remove(array_remove(split(replace(replace(categories, '['), ']'), '\''), ''::variant), '\n '::variant)

Output:
[
  "Home & Kitchen / Kitchen & Dining / Dining & Entertaining / Glassware & Drinkware",
  "Home & Kitchen / Kitchen & Dining / Dining & Entertaining / Novelty / Drinkware / Coffee Mugs"
]

Despite string escaping this solution doesn't take when I apply to a model in dbt. I receive a syntax error with the next column "unexpected."
I see the issue is directly tied to the outer replace handling single quotes i.e. '\"' which already aims to handle replacing single quotes safely, but apparently not in dbt.
Any thoughts/recommendations welcomed!

can you share the query that dbt created and sent to snowflake?

The below approach should work with the data you provided, and feels less convoluted than the one you tried out:
select 
  ['Home & Kitchen / Kitchen & Dining / Dining & Entertaining / Glassware & Drinkware','Home & Kitchen / Kitchen & Dining / Dining & Entertaining / Novelty / Drinkware / Coffee Mugs']::variant 
    as my_variant,
  array_distinct(strtok_to_array(array_to_string(my_variant, '/'), '/'));

which returns:
[   "Home & Kitchen ",   " Kitchen & Dining ",   " Dining & Entertaining ",   " Glassware & Drinkware",   " Novelty ",   " Drinkware ",   " Coffee Mugs" ]

